# guava - bloomfilter: is it possible to get a true-negative for a value that was **previously** a false-positive?

Tags: java, guava, bloom-filter, false-positive

If I understand correctly, once an item is `put` inside a guava bloom filter, `mightContain` will always return true. If the filter returns `false` on `mightContain`, then the value has never been put inside the filter. What I'm wondering is for the values that `might` be a false positive at a given moment, as more values are put in, the once false-positives might become true-negatives later on (if they are not put in, of course).

Something like this:

```
GuavaBloomFilter<Integer> bf = new GuavaBloomFilter<>(blah, blah);
# if I start checking, none of the values should return tru at the monent
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(5)); // false
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(10)); // false
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(15)); // false
# fine
# let's put in a value now
bf.put(10);
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(5));
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(10)); // true, every time from now on
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(15));
```

On the last 3 checks, when checking for 10, it will *always* return true. For 5 and 15, it *might* return true. Suppose that for 5 we get false (never put inside), for 15 we get a false positive.

So, we continue:

```
bf.put(5);
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(5)); // true, every single time from now on
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(10)); // true, every time from now on
System.out.println(bd.mightContain(15));
```

So.... now, when checking for 5, we will `always` get true. Is it possible that because of the state change inside the bloom filter, the result for checking 15 which was previously a false-positive, might return a true-negative value?

Answer (score 1):

For a true Bloom filter, the bits only ever go from 0 to 1, never back - so the result of a `mightContain` call can only ever go from `false` to `true`, never back, because `mightContain` returns true if a certain subset of all bits are 1, and once they're 1 they'll stay 1.

Guava's implementation is indeed a true Bloom filter, since the `BloomFilter.put` method ([source](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/86eabf1fe6991cf7fbc65980dac59a604303b362/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.java#L152)) delegates to `Strategy.put` ([source](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/86eabf1fe6991cf7fbc65980dac59a604303b362/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.java#L68)), an interface implemented in `BloomFilterStrategies` ([source](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/86eabf1fe6991cf7fbc65980dac59a604303b362/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilterStrategies.java)). The Bloom filter's bits are stored in a `LockFreeBitArray` named `bits`, and the strategy only calls its `bitSize`, `set` and `get` methods. Of those, only `set` changes bits ([source](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/86eabf1fe6991cf7fbc65980dac59a604303b362/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilterStrategies.java#L169)), and it only uses the bitwise 'or' operator `|` to change them. This can never change a 1 back to a 0.

So, it is indeed impossible for a value which was previously a false-positive to later become a true-negative.